# PHP ends or breaks randomly using Facebook API

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using the Facebook openGraph API for PHP. Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

header("Location: index.php");
break;

}

$fbconfig['appid' ]     = "APPID";
$fbconfig['secret']     = "SECRET";
$fbconfig['baseurl']    = "http://blah.com/"; 

$user = null; 
try{
    include_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
}
    // Create our Application instance.
try {
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));
} catch (Exception $e) { echo "ERROR: ".$e; } 

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'email,publish_stream,read_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl'].'blah.php'
        )
);



$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array( 'next' => ($fbconfig['baseurl'].'blah.php') ));


//if user is logged in and session is valid.
if ($user ){

    header("Location;$loginUrl");
    break;

}


?>
```

Now, this works on other pages (the Facebook part) but on this page only (same dir as other pages) The browser thinks that the PHP ends at "'appId'  =>" and from then on interprets it as html. So I get this in my browser:

http://cl.ly/image/1y2a2F0e3I35

Sorry for the weird cropped picture, but I can't divulge the name or intent of the business.

There is HTML after the PHP on the real site and I can give this + js if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: If you have the same block of code twice (or more), you should consider creating a function or an include that does the job for you. A side effect of this is that you'd remove the offending line (where there's probably a hidden "end of file" character) and all pages should work the same way.

Answer (score -1):

```
     your header is wrong.......try following......
        header("Location:$loginUrl");
        and also if you don't get facebook user id then you have to redirect to login page but you did reverse.may do following
    //if user is not loggin
        if (empty($user)){
            header("Location:$loginUrl");
        }else{
           try {
                $userInfo = $facebook->api("/$user");
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $userInfo=null;
            }
        }
```